# Lock/Unlock critical section of code in UIView animation completion block - Swift

Tags: swift

How do I lock and unlock a critical section of code in a UIView animation completion block using Swift (in a subclassed UIView)?

```
func MoveCard(sourcePile: Pile, destPile: Pile) {

    // Temporarily disable user interaction
    disableUserInteraction()

    // Move card from source pile to destination pile
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1) {
        () -> Void in

        // Move card center
        self.center = destPile.center

        // CRITICAL SECTION OF CODE
        // Add card to destination pile array
        destPile.cards.append(sourcePile.cards.last!)
        // Remove card from source pile array
        sourcePile.cards.removeLast()

        // Reenable user interaction
        enableUserInteraction()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1, animations: {
    // your animation code
}, completion: { (complete: Bool) in
    // your completion code
})
```

Comment: Greg, Thanks... I've add the completion code... but I'm still interested in protecting the Critical Section of Code to prevent reading/writing while the pile arrays are being updated.  Will this code work?

    // Critical lock variable
    let critLock = NSLock()

    }, completion: {

        // Upon completion of animation
        (finished: Bool) in

            // Add critical lock
            self.critLock.lock()

            // Critical Section code

            // Remove critical lock
            self.critLock.unlock()
    })